# purrr:: map and lag functions, syntax with nested data frame

Tags: r, purrr, lag

I'm struggling with the syntax for performing operations on elements on nested dataframes. Using this example:

```
> df1 <- tibble(P=c(101,101,102,102,103,103,101,101,102,102,103,103))
> df2 <- tibble(C=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
> df3 <- tibble(SmpDate=as.Date(c("2019-11-01","2019-11-01","2019-11-01","2019-11-01","2019-11-01","2019-11-01","2019-11-02","2019-11-02","2019-11-02","2019-11-02","2019-11-02","2019-11-02")))
> df4 <- tibble(Fl=round(runif(12,0.1,5),2))
> df <- data.frame(df1,df2,df3,df4) #create the data.frame
> df_n <- df %>% group_by(P,C,SmpDate) %>% nest(data=c(SmpDate,Fl))
> 
> glimpse(df_n)
Observations: 6
Variables: 3
Groups: P, C [6]
$ P    <dbl> 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103
$ C    <dbl> 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
$ data <list<df[,2]>> 18201.00, 18202.00, 0.50, 3.11, 18201.00, 18202.00, 2.04, 0.86, 18201.00, 18202.00, 2.07, 1.59, 18201.00, 18202.00, 4.51, 2.83, 18201.0...
>
```

I want to perform operations on the Fl variable and the SmpDate in the data list using lag functions and some conditional statements.  I understand that I should be able to use the purrr::map functions but I can't seem to get the syntax right to address the individual elements.
For example, keeping in mind that I realize this will not work:

```
cp1<-function(df){
day(SmpDate)*Fl
}
cp2<-function(df){
  (SmpDate-lag(SmpDate,n=1L))*Fl
}
```

Using mutate and conditions based on the SmpDate, I will select the function to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at something. But your post lack enough context for this approach to make sense.

```r
df_n %>% 
  mutate(
    cp1 = data %>% map(. %>% pmap(function(SmpDate, Fl, ...) {
      lubridate::day(SmpDate)*Fl
    })),

    cp2 = data %>% map(. %>% pmap(function(SmpDate, Fl, ...) {
      (SmpDate-lag(SmpDate,n=1L))*Fl
    }))
  ) %>% 
  # unnest(c(cp1, cp2))
  identity()
```

Comment: I apologize for the lack of context.  I was perhaps trying to condense my question a bit too much in an attempt to avoid adding too much unnecessary content. The cp1, cp2 functions will be applied such that the first date in each group of P,C as determined by min(SmpDate) will have the cp1 function applied, the second and  subsequent dates within the grouping will have cp2 applied and the final SmpDate in each grouping as determined by max(SmpDate) will have a third function applied.  The functions are a bit more elaborate than in the example but hopefully I can modify once I understand better

Comment: I should add that the result of the function should be output to a new, 3rd column within the nested dataframe so that there is a value for each SmpDate,Fl pair.